# Remove tick/check box from ASP.NET Checkbox control

Tags: asp.net, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have this CheckBoxList control and to each ListItem of it, have set the Text property to the img HTML tag so it displays an image.

I am trying to remove the tick/check box from the checkboxes of a ASP.NET CheckBoxList control when i click on each item.

My code does this. Every time i click on some check box, the **SelectedIndexChanged** event fires up and it does some saving of some data in my database. And when the saving is done and  the page is refreshed i want to check/tick box of the checkbox item that was clicked not to be there anymore and the checkbox to be disabled cause i don't want the user to able able to click it again. I have tried to tried to set the Enable and Selected properties to False, and also add an attribute to the CheckboxList control, but without success. Here is my code.

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="Services" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" CellPadding="10"             
CellSpacing="15" RepeatLayout="Table" 
                         Font-Size="Large" RepeatDirection="Vertical" TextAlign="Right" 
AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true">

<asp:ListItem Value="Facebook" Text="<img src='/ServiceIcons/facebook.png'  
title='Facebook' />" />
<asp:ListItem Value="Googleplus" Text="<img src='/ServiceIcons/googleplus.png' 
title='Google+' />" />
<asp:ListItem Value="LinkedIn" Text="<img src='/ServiceIcons/linkedin.png' 
title='LinkedIn' />" />
<asp:ListItem Value="RSS" Text="<img src='/ServiceIcons/rss.png' title='RSS' />" />
<asp:ListItem Value="Skype" Text="<img src='/ServiceIcons/skype.png' title='Skype' />" 
/>

</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

And in the code behind i do this:

```
  Private Sub Services_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
  System.EventArgs) Handles Services.SelectedIndexChanged

       -----Storing to database code here------

        Services.Items(Services.SelectedIndex).Enabled = False
        Services.Items(Services.SelectedIndex).Attributes.Add("class", 
        "displayCheckBox")
        Services.Items(Services.SelectedIndex).Selected = False


  End Sub
```

And the css class here:

```
  .displayCheckBox input{display:none;}
```

After the the event does the storing in the database and the page is refreshed, the checkbox that was selected is disabled but it shows the tick/check box, and i don't want it to show it if is selected.

Any one has an idea. I have searched a lot, but it seems that the CheckBoxList control doesn't provide much costumizing options.

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the checkbox from the checkboxlist, on SelectedIndexChanged event, try this:

```
Private Sub Services_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Services.SelectedIndexChanged

    '-----Storing to database code here------

    Services.Items.RemoveAt(Services.SelectedIndex)
End Sub
```

Comment: Hello KLP, thank you for your time.
No, i don't want to remove the checkbox from the checkboxlist,  just want the tick/check box not to appear on the checkbox that was clicked by the user, when the user clicks it.